# How do I use different card layouts for varying content?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-cardview

Displaying a certain layout for a card, when using `CardView`, is simple enough.

I've created an XML layout for my card, and instantiate that XML layout to the View using `LayoutInflater`.

More specifically:

```
View largeCardView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view, viewGroup, false);
```

Which is called in the `onCreate()` method of my `RecyclerAdapter`. The `onCreate` method then returns this `largeCardVew`. This works perfectly and the cards are displayed as they are laid out in the XML file.

But what if I want to display different cards for different content? Is it possible to show different cards for different things, but have them all in the same `RecyclerView`?

For example, if I know before hand that there will be a string passed into a `TextView` in the card, and this string can only have two values "Large" and "Small", how can I use one type of XML file to use with the "Large" text, and another XML file to use with the "Small" text?

Here is an example (taken from [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store)):

[image]

As you can see in the picture, there are two different card types, with different layouts (ignore the orange button). Is there a way to achieve a similar thing, and have the cards in the same `RecyclerView`?

Comment: this guide may help -- https://guides.codepath.com/android/Heterogenous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's similar to how you would create a single card layout, but instead of having a single `.xml` and a single `ViewHolder`, each layout needs to have its *own* `.xml` file defining it, and a `ViewHolder` class.

The method which was found to be very important, is the [`getItemViewType(int position)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#getItemViewType%28int%29) method in the RecyclerView.Adapter class. By default, this method returns 0, assuming a single layout for the `viewType` being used (in this case, a `cardView`). Since more than a single type is needed, I had to define them.

I then created an array of integers (called `cardViewTypes`), defining which layouts get used for which type of data. Since you should already have some sort of dataset for the content of the cards (whether it's a `List` or a `HashMap`), it's important to make sure that the data matches up with the view types.

In my case, I wanted to have 4 different card layouts, so I defined each in their own `.xml` file and gave them unique names. Then, in my `RecyclerView.Adapter` class, I created a separate class which extended `ViewHolder` for each layout. I made sure that each integer in my `viewType` array matched up with my data and called `getItemViewType`.

I then check the view type in the `onCreateViewHolder` method of the `RecyclerView.Adapter`, and inflate the corresponding view, which is then bound in `onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder, int)`.

And the result is differing card layouts for different content.